# C# Object with unset key value types

Tags: c#

My goal:
I want to create a system that can have key value pairs but that I don't need to beforehand set either the key or the value's data type

What I am trying to emulate to an extent is pythons dictionaries

example of what I want

```
{
  "hotbar"=
  {
             {"slot_1"={"item"="dirt","amount"=3},
             {"slot_3"={"item"="shovel","amount"=1,"usesLeft"=135}
  }
  "walkspeed"=10
  "jumpPower"=15
  "position"={"x"=10,"y"=3,"z"=31.3}
```

*similar to Minecraft's nbt system is my goal*

the syntax does not need to be perfectly the same just as long as I can store it with a key and value without it mattering what type of key and value it is

And I want to be able to read and write individual values from this (including nested values)
and also to loop through all of the key value pairs as well

*please recomend me better tags*

Comment: Dictionary<string, object> will allow you to store any value you like. You can get any value back out but it will be up to you to cast to the actual type before using it.

Comment: C#, unlike Python, is a strongly typed language. The proper way to do this would be to make classes and use a `Dictionary<T, T>` to strong them. If you wanted to do it more dynamically, rather than statically typed, then you could use a 'dynamic' type: `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`

Comment: NBT is a binary format, so I assume you're talking about its "stringified" form, SNBT... JSON is a better format for textual representation. Newtonsoft.Json has the `JToken`-based types that essentially will give you what you're looking for. Just use that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Key value things is Dictionary
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-dictionary
but in OOP you can just use List of objects
e.g.
//Design Objects (classes)

```
public class Hotbar { //Hotbar class
   public string key_name {get;set;}
   public stirng item {get;set;}
   public int amount{get;set;}   
   public int usesLeft{get;set;}
}

public class YourMainClass{
  public List<Hotbar> hotbar_List {get;set;}
  public int walkspeed {get;set;}
  public int jumpPower {get;set;}
  public PositionObj position {get;set;} // go create object of position
  public YourMainClass(){
   // constructor  Init List 
   hotbar_List   =new List<hotbar>();
  }

}
```

example how to use

```
YourMainClass targetObj =new YourMainClass();
// create new Hotbar
  Hotbar  hotbar1  =new Hotbar();
  hotbar1.key_name  = "slot_1";
  hotbar1.item  ="dirt";
  hotbar1.amount= 3;
// add  hotbar #1
 targetObj.hotbar_List.Add(hotbar1);

// get hot bar slot_1
 Hotbar thatHot = targetObj.hotbar_List.Where(o=>o.key_name  =="slot_1").FirstOrDefault();

// for looping - will loop if there are obj in List
 foreach( Hotbar  oneHotBar from  targetObj.hotbar_List  ){
  // do something with hotbar   Obj call oneHotBar 
   string name_of_item = oneHotBar.key_name  ; 
  // try minus amount 
   if( oneHotBar .key_name  =="slot_1" )
   {
      oneHotBar. amount =  oneHotBar. amount-1;
   }
 }
```

p.s. sorry I'm not fluent with Dictionary and Dynamic type so the code provided is only for strongly-typed classes , please wait for others.